# XPATH (eXistdb) how to replace literal &nbsp; in HTTP request content

Tags: xpath, xquery, exist-db

Our users are entering data into a browser form, including text that may contain non-breaking spaces. When they save the data to the server (via an AJAX request to eXist-db), it sends the following in the HTTP POST payload content with `&nbsp;`:

```
<request type="edit_collection" id="TC0002">    
  <about>Chômei a donc rédigé un recueil d’anecdotes, 
   s’intégrant dans le genre de la «&nbsp;littérature 
   d’anecdotes&nbsp;» (setsuwa bungaku), qui remonte 
   au début du IXe siècle.</about> 
</request>
```

The module that begins processing the HTTP request first assigns the payload data to $content:

`let $content := request:get-data()`

The above happens without error because `$content` is simply a string of characters, not yet parsed as XML. Only when I later pass `$content` on for XML parsing does the error arise, rejecting `&nbsp;` with an error:

```
exerr:ERROR cannot convert xs:string('&lt;request 
type=&quot;edit_collection&quot; date=&quot;TC0002&quot;&gt;
&lt;about&gt;Chômei a donc rédigé un recueil d’anecdotes, s’intégrant 
dans le genre de la «&nbsp;littérature d’anecdotes&nbsp;» (setsuwa 
bungaku), qui remonte au début du IXe siècle.&lt;/about&gt; 
&lt;/request&gt;') to a node set 

XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
```

However, a simple replacement of `&nbsp;` before parsing is not legal, that is XPATH (in XQuery as implemented in eXist?) won't accept `&nbsp;` in this formulation:

`let $content := replace(request:get-data(),"&nbsp;","&#160;")`

Is there some other way to replace `&nbsp;` before parsing as XML?

(My preference is to do this cleaning server-side and not in the Javascript)

Comment: How do you end up with that POST request body in the first place? Which content type does the body of the POST request have?

Comment: I've added some information below Michael Kay's response...

Answer (score 1):

The snippet you have shown is not legal XML - to be well-formed it would need to have a DTD that declared the entity `nbsp`. So it's not clear how you're processing it, or why it gets as far as it does.

If there were a DTD, then the content seen by the XQuery processor (as delivered by the XML parser) would be the expansion of the entity (presumably a single xA0 character) and the query wouldn't have to do any work to understand it or translate it.

Perhaps there's something else happening here: perhaps the snippet you've shown is actually inside a CDATA section, so it's being passed through unchanged by the XML parser?

==UPDATE==

You've explained that you're actually processing a character string that contains the six-character sequence `&nbsp;` and you want to replace it with the single character xA0.

In abstract terms, the XPath expression `replace('&nbsp;', '_')` (where '_' is xA0) will do this; the question is how to express this in concrete syntax, and this depends on the host language. It's also an area where XQuery isn't exactly the same as XPath. In particular, XQuery uses XML rules for escaping special characters in string literals (but not elsewhere), while XPath doesn't do any escaping or unescaping, it relies on the host language to do it.

In XQuery, I think the correct expression is `replace('&amp;nbsp;', '&#xa0;')`.

But there's another question here: why is the browser sending ill-formed XML in its HTTP POST request? Well-formed XML doesn't contain undefined entity references like `&nbsp;`. Rather than trying to repair the XML in the recipient, shouldn't you be looking at why you're getting broken XML from the sender?

Comment: The Javascript in the browser creates XML for the HTTP POST content, sending it as a string of characters. When the XQuery module uses the function `request:get-data()` to access the HTTP content, it does not yet apply a 'data type', it just assigns that content to `$content`. Only when I then send `$content` on to be parsed as XML does the error arise, stating that `xs:string cannot be converted to a node set`. The error only occurs when `&nbsp;` appears in the content.  As such, I'm looking as simply as possible to replace &nbsp;  with &#160; while it is still in effect in format xs:string.

Comment: I have added more detail to my question in hopes that it responds to your statement "So it's not clear how you're processing it, or why it gets as far as it does."

Comment: Indeed, I will be revising the Javascript to not send undefined entity references. At the same time I would have thought, foolishly, this to be a fairly simple matter of effectively replacing text within a string. But it  turns out after different tests that applying **any**  `replace()` to `request:get-data()` effectively strips out the XML passed to the next function (ie. the xs:string no longer contains `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc.) Evidently I'm missing something and I need to research more.

Comment: I think you're confused about whether this is unparsed XML (a string) or parsed XML (a tree of nodes). If replace() is losing the XML structure, that suggests it's a tree of nodes; but if it's a tree of nodes, then it can't contain unresolved entity references.